# flask-babel: how to translate variables

Tags: python, flask, python-babel, flask-babel

I am using flask-babel for translating a Flask-based web application. I really want to know how can I translate the content of a variable, say `foo`.

I try `{{ _(foo) }}`, but when I update the `.po` files like this:

```
pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -k lazy_gettext -o messages.pot .
pybabel update -i messages.pot -d translations
```

nothing is displayed for translating with the content of the `foo` var.

All is OK with constants strings, like `{{ _("goo")}}`.

Comment: If I try: `{% trans %}{{activity.title}}{% endtrans %}`, I get `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got '.'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot *extract* a variable, because in the expression `_(some_variable)` `some_variable` is looked up at run-time.  If you are taking `some_variable` from a list of static values then the static values *will* be extracted.  For example:

```
COLORS_OF_MAGIC = [_("green"), _("red"), _("blue"), _("white"), _("black")]

def color_for_index(index):
    if not (0 < index > len(COLORS_OF_MAGIC)):
        index = 0

    return COLORS_OF_MAGIC[index]

def do_work():
    index = get_index_from_user()
    some_variable = color_for_index(index)
    return _("You chose ") + _(some_variable) + _(" as the color of magic")
```

will have the values: `green`, `red`, `blue`, `white`, `black`, `You chose`, and `as the color of magic` in the PO file.

If, on the other hand, you are trying to translate user-provided strings then you will need another solution, as Babel is a static translation service.

Comment: So is there any solution for dynamic translation?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497489/translating-strings-from-database-flask-babel) say the same: babel cannot translate dynamics fields, but who can.

Comment: Is this the sort of application that you could / should ask the user to provide alternative translations for their text (e. g. a CMS) or something where the end-user will generally *not* be providing translations and someone might want to see the content in another language (e. g. a blog)?

Comment: I have the values of my variables from a file. Is there any way to translate that? I could define:  `COLORS_OF_MAGIC = yaml.load(file)`?

Comment: you example does not work. I only get `You chose` and `as the color of magic` in my .pot file. No value of "green",...

Comment: @somenxavier - my fault entirely - I forgot the `_(...)` invocation around the static values for the colors.

Comment: ok. Turning to my original question, can I load the contents of one file statically? And so take advance to this trick?

Comment: @somenxavier - that would be better done by a build script that takes the contents of that file and adds it to the PO file, honestly (if I am understanding you correctly).

Comment: it's a pitty to have to build a custom script. I thought Babel was enough capable of doing this. I have to reinvent the wheel...

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem. I needed to translate month names that passed to jinja2 at runtime. The solution I came up with is to pass translated names. Then all I had to do is declare a static list of names as mentioned in the accepted answer. Hope this helps.