# Babel - Using both `msgstr` and `msgid` without duplicate static strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-babel, flask-babel

Take this as an example while I tried to minimize code duplication.

```
msg = 'User request is completed'
logging.info(msg) 
reply(_(msg))     # Babel would failed to extract the variable `msg`.
```

I know babel cannot extract [variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34579316/4123703) but I'd like to find a way to keep both `msgid` and `msgstr` in my code while making babel extract without the problem.

To keep both `msgid` and `msgstr`, I have to write duplicate code

```py
from flask_babel import _
# I'd like to find a way to just change one line instead of two.
logging.info('User request is completed') # 1. log msgid
reply(_('User request is completed'))     # 2. reply msgstr which is returned by `_()`
```

I wan to log with `msgid` and reply translated `msgstr`.
It's easier to lookup the log in a fixed language or it'd be hard for looking into the log in *Klingon*. (No offense to Klingon)

Eg: Log `User request is completed` while reply `qaStaHvIS qemlI'`.

I'm using flask_babel but I believe this question should be common for babel. I cannot find a solution for it. Probably my skill for search engine is not good enough. Please let me know if there is any related post.

My naive way to deal with it:

```
# `msg` is translated string 'qaStaHvIS qemlI'
# `msgid` is the id 'User request is completed'
msg, msgid = gettext_and_id('User request is completed') # No such function in babel
logging.info(msgid)
reply(msg)
```

However I did check the source code of flask-babel and there is no similar functions.
Indeed, I could make a helper function on my own, but I'd like to have a better solution.

```
def gettext_and_id(msgid):
    return gettext(msgid), msgid
```

However this solution doesn't fix everything.
If I want to use `Some {file}` as a string for substitution, then it's still tedious...

```
filename = 'neverland'
# ... file doesn't exist
msg, msgid = gettext_and_id('{file} is not found')
msg = msg.format(file=filename)
msgid = msgid.format(file=filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Babel won't be able to pick up the string `t`'s contents into a catalog from the expression `_(t)`, because that would involve either static analysis to try and figure out if `t` is statically assigned, or actually running the code and capturing all `_()` invocations, both of which are a bit tough to do.

You can [configure a custom keyword](https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/setup.html#method-mapping), say, `msgid`, and define that function in your program to simply return the same string at runtime.

Then you can do

```
msg = msgid('User request is completed')
logging.info(msg) 
reply(_(msg))
```

and Babel would pick up the message, but it would only actually get translated by the `_()` call.

Alternately, if you don't want to pay the runtime price for that identity `msgid` function, [you could write a custom Babel extractor](https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/messages.html#writing-extraction-methods) and tag your messages with some special syntax, e.g. here a `# msgid` comment:

```
msg = 'User request is completed'  # msgid
logging.info(msg) 
reply(_(msg))
```